# Mobile view of salesforce Dynamic Form is showing all fields as editable even though they are read only in UI Behavior

Tags: salesforce1-app, dynamic-forms

In my component, among 10 field we added only 3 fields as editable rest all are read-only. There is no problem when we are trying to create a new record. But, when trying to edit the existing record, all the 10 fields are showing as editable in mobile. In desktop its working fine.

Comment: Looks like for mobile view, it'll pick fields from layout and show in phone view. If you want different fields either you need to create multiple pagelayouts and multiple record detail - mobile views and render using filters

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Forms are desktop only. If you want to control behavior of fields on mobile, go-to *lightning app builder*, switch to *Phone* view, then drag and drop *record detail mobile* component(if not already present), this component would have specified page layout assigned. You can change behavior of required field by going to respective page layout and clicking on the wrench/properties button of the field in question.

In short: If you want read-only to work on mobile, specify field property in page layout accordingly.